# Wordpress query_post by category not querying

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get all the colleagues from a custom post type that are linked to the a category. It doesn't want to work in the slightest It returns every result under the category, not the specific custom post type. Can anyone help, am I missing something. $current_segment is bringing in the right slug.

Code is:

```
<?php
    /**
    * Query post based on $current_segment value
    */
    query_posts( array(
      'post_type'     => 'colleagues',
      'category_name' => $current_segment
      ) 
    );
    ?>
```

Thanks

Managed to find the answer, you need to set the taxonomy as the category and then the term as the $current_segment.

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'colleagues', 'taxonomy'=> 'category', 'term' => $current_segment ) );
```

Comment: And the `colleagues` posts are assigned to the `$current_segment` category?

Comment: they are assigned correctly.

Comment: I think the issue is to do with the custom post type as when I change the current_segement variable the results change.

Comment: Have you tried adding a [wp_reset_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) before your query? Is it possible a different query is affecting it?

Comment: just tried that - still not working.